# Using IF statements with variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

Sorry if I'm asking a very silly question, but I'm a bit rusty in writing simple batch scripts but I'm running into an issue. I wanted to write a script that will change a local admin password depending on the day of the week. The script runs but just runs the first label and skips the IF statements, and I'm a little unsure of what the issue might be.

```
FOR /F "skip=1" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek') DO (
  set DOW=%%A
)

IF DOW == 0 goto SUN
IF DOW == 1 goto MON
IF DOW == 2 goto TUE
IF DOW == 3 goto WED
IF DOW == 4 goto THU
IF DOW == 5 goto FRI
IF DOW == 6 goto SAT

:SUN
net user admin Password0
GOTO END

:MON
net user admin Password1
GOTO END

:TUE
net user admin Password2
GOTO END

:WED
net user admin Password3
GOTO END

:THU
net user admin Password4
GOTO END

:FRI
net user admin Password5
GOTO END

:SAT
net user admin Password6
GOTO END

:END
```

Answer (score 2):

To read the value inside DOW variable, the syntax is `%DOW%`.

```
if %DOW%==0 goto SUN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the below. Also note that you need to prefix the label with a Colon (:) which seems to be missing in your code.

```
if %DOW% EQU 0 goto :SUN
```

Cheers, G